# Can Notepad++ automatically split a text file into multiple files?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, notepad++, text-editing, text-formatting

I have a text file that contains a massive amount of words that I would like to make into a number of different text files.  Specifically I need to take every 100 words in this file and make a separate text file.  So, for example, my existing file has 5000 words.  This would create 50 files with 100 words each in them.  Is this possible with notepad++?

Comment: @QuickishFM  Thanks for the reply.  I didnt realize this was such a common question.  I am using windows 10 but I have ubuntu 18.04 loaded on another HDD that I can boot to with a computer reset.  Thanks for the link.  I have been researching.

Comment: “I have ubuntu 18.04 loaded on another HDD that I can boot to with a computer reset.” -- Do not forget that you can also [run Ubuntu under WSL in Windows 10](https://linuxhint.com/install_ubuntu_windows_10_wsl/). Windows drives are mounted under `/mnt` by default, `C:` as `/mnt/c` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

you can use Gsplit, as alternative

https://www.gdgsoft.com/gsplit

Gsplit -> Other Properties -> SELECT - "Do not Add Gtsplit tags to pieces"

**Go to Express Button:**

**1.** Split this file: put the file path  (ex. `D:\Test\file.txt` )

**2.** Copy this pieces to: put the place where you want to put your new files. AFTER you have converted, you must rename the new disk.gsd files to .txt.

Size of each pieces: `add 2 more zeros: 5000000  (this means 5 mb)`

IF the message appears `"Warning: do you realy want to switch the pieces to 5000000 GB?"` you must **click OK**

Comment: Explaining HOW to use GSplit will make this an answer. Right now this is only a comment.

Comment: I just edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done in Linux with a variety of tools, `split` being one. I'm assuming you are using Windows however, as you mentioned Notepad++. I don't think theres native Windows tools for it, but you can simply google the problem and find many solutions for it online. This is a common problem and there exist a variety of ways to solve it. Here is an example of one that may work, though not fully automated: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/12370/splitting-or-breaking-one-file-into-multiple-smaller-ones. I suggest you research this further and then come back with a specific question on a method, due to how common this question is.

Answer (score 0):

As for **A BETTER AND QUICK ALTERNATIVE** to split txt files, you can use [git-bash](https://gitforwindows.org/)

1. Open git-bash in the folder you have the .txt files
2. (Right click inside the folder -> Git Bash Here) and Use this commands:

`cat *.txt | split -b 1m   (split all files into a maximum of 1mb)`

`cat *.txt | split -b 500k  (split all files into a maximum of 500kb)`