# Need to Split 5M Lines Text File into separate CSV files

Tags: notepad++, csv

I want to create CSV file from every 1048574 lines from a large CSV file which as 5M lines.
I want to use something like Notepad++ to divide it out into different files. How can I do that ?

Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Notepad++ automatically split a text file into multiple files?](https://superuser.com/questions/1399737/can-notepad-automatically-split-a-text-file-into-multiple-files)

Comment: Notepad++ is probably not the right tool for this task.

Comment: You can do it in Notepad++ in theory, but if you don't have a really capable machine, it'll lag very heavily or even crash. GUI apps are not too suitable for this large types of data.

Comment: thanks for your all help. I will use Gsplit

Comment: https://github.com/philoushka/LargeFileSplitter

Answer (score 0):

As the limit suggests loading the data in LO/Excel, you can also use [GS-Calc](https://citadel5.com/gs-calc.htm) (a spreadsheet with 12 million rows). You can define the splitting limit and save both split xlsx and text files.